# Cocos2dx: Garbled bitmap image from android

Tags: android, c++, bitmap, java-native-interface, cocos2d-x

Note: Using the latest of cocos 2.x

Hi there. I'm trying to pass a bitmap through jni and convert it to a sprite to display, but the image created using CCTexture2d's **initWithData** is completely garbled. I've looked at other forum posts here, but even after following those as closely as possible, nothing works. Note that we are not going to use a path for the image (and it isn't an option).

There are a few issues that I will break down:

**What kind of data is necessary?**

The initWithData method has no documentation as to what kind of data it even takes- byte array? Pixel array? It seems other people have used byte array and got it working, so that is what we have gone with. This is the code to get the byte array, but are we supposed to use PNG or JPEG format?

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bAOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, bAOS);
byte[] bytes = bAOS.toByteArray();
```

**Getting the data to cocos**

We are using some other convenience methods to write jni messages as json data which gets converted to a **CCDictionary**. The Byte array gets turned into a CCArray of a bunch of ints, which we can then loop through and assign...to what kind of array? "byte" isn't a valid primitive in c++. Online I've seen an **int** array:

```
CCArray *bytes = (CCArray*)dictionary->objectForKey("bytes");
int byteArray[bytes->count()];
for (int i = 0; i < bytes->count(); i++) {
CCNumber *v = (CCNumber*)bytes->objectAtIndex(i);
byteArray[i] = v->getIntValue();
};
```

and I've tried a **char** array as well, but neither worked.

**CCTexture2d? CCImage?**

Ok, so now we have our supposed byte array, we can render the image. Do we use CCTexture2d or CCImage?

For CCTexture2d (we know the image is 20x20 px):

```
CCTexture2D *texture = new CCTexture2D();
texture->initWithData(byteArray,kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888,20,20,CCSizeMake(20,20));
```

The image is garbled.

For CCImage...what is the length? I've seen length calculated as the image witdth * image height, or as the actual length of the byte array. Your guess is as good as mine, as I have never gotten a CCImage to work.

```
CCImage *image = new CCImage();
image->initWithImageData(byteArray,length,CCImage::kFmtPng,20,20,8);
```

Once we have a CCImage, we can set it to a texture using CCTexture2d's initWithImage function.

Now that we have the Texture, making a sprite with it should be simple:

```
CCSprite *sprite = CCSprite::createWithTexture(texture);
```

Which works, in as much as a sprite is created. The image is trash though.

So, what exactly is wrong here?
**How do we get the data from the bitmap?**
**How do we make the data something that cocos can render?**
**Texture2d or Image? What are the parameters?**

For kicks, here is the image we are testing:

[image: Test bitmap]

And here is the byte array as Android reports it:

```
[-119,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68,82,0,0,0,40,0,0,0,40,8,2,0,0,0,3,-100,47,58,0,0,0,3,115,66,73,84,8,8,8,-37,-31,79,-32,0,0,0,-71,73,68,65,84,88,-123,-19,-44,-79,13,-125,48,16,-123,-31,-97,8,-118,-48,96,37,-108,40,-70,34,3,-48,-91,-124,81,24,-115,77,48,27,-64,6,-98,32,50,19,-112,5,48,-123,69,20,41,-36,-55,-35,-45,-13,-41,-100,-114,21,-30,-34,64,-45,48,-60,-74,-41,11,63,26,-123,21,86,88,97,-123,21,86,-8,-60,112,106,-101,-56,-90,-61,11,83,48,-10,6,39,44,38,-108,39,-51,16,9,11,69,-117,8,-127,-81,-89,-102,-66,99,-82,67,-11,116,108,35,97,88,-124,121,-81,109,-4,78,120,-66,-27,82,88,-31,-81,77,26,-35,-12,20,19,66,-32,-128,92,51,-71,21,46,47,-19,-15,-80,67,122,58,-61,-10,109,-86,114,-9,122,-40,-22,-19,-114,-121,23,-52,76,13,-19,102,-6,-52,-20,-67,112,73,57,-122,-22,-25,91,46,-123,21,-2,63,-8,3,120,-72,71,35,-19,75,10,-28,0,0,0,0,73,69,78,68,-82,66,96,-126]
```

And here is the result (the image is not 20 x 20 though- scaled by cocos to fit density, probably)

[image: Broken image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated